# Objective-c method is not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, parameters

a custom method i have made is not being called and i cant figure out why.

it is a method that takes in a boolean parameter, but when i call the command from a button:

```
[self myMethod:TRUE];
```

the system doesnt do any thing. i can tell that the function works because when i run the command from:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self myMethod:TRUE];
}
```

the program functions as i would expect given the different boolean valued.

my method is defined similarly to:

```
- (void)myMethod:(BOOL) theBool
{
    if (theBool){
        //stuff if theBool is true
    } else {
        //stuff if theBool is false
    }
}
```

i don't get any errors but it just doesn't change anything on the screen.

Comment: when called from a button - can you explain in more detail what you did and what exactly happens?

Comment: Have you made sure your button method gets called when you tap it?

Comment: Volker, well i created a method by ctrl+dragging to the .h file. it autogenerated the corresponding method in the .m file where i put [self myMethod:TRUE];

Comment: Tander, im pretty certain the button is getting called, because when i hover over the connection, the correct controller is highlighted on the storyboard.

Comment: Are you trying to connect the button directly to this `myMethod:`?

Comment: Chuck, no, the method that it is lined to calls [self myMethod:TRUE];

Comment: You can check if the method is being called by placing a breakpoint inside your myMethod method. Run your app, press on your button, and check how it reacts.

Comment: You can use the debugger and set breakpoints as Cubia has suggested, or you can use NSLogs to trace program execution.  Add an NSLog at the beginning of the button-press handler, and at the beginning of your custom method.

Comment: As mentioned above, first check if your method is actually being called (don't trust drag-and-drop too much, is an xcode pitfall).